# How to prove the shape of the "Flower of Venus"

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, mathematical-astronomy

[This](https://i.imgur.com/PqJy8lX.gifv) is the gif that inspired this question. So, considering that Venus and Earth's orbits are coplanar concentric circles and that their orbits follow a 13:8 (difference of five) ratio, how can I prove this five-fold symmetry?

I've been playing around in GeoGebra and created symmetries with [other numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYjzP.jpg), for example, a 'ratio difference' of 9 creates a nine-fold symmetry as seen above.

What I want is to, using relatively simple math tools (I'm a high school student), analytically prove how and why this symmetry corresponds to the difference in the ratio.

One of my ideas was to reach the equation of the line between the two planets and prove that it passes five (or whatever difference) times through the centre of the orbits, given that each time the trace passes over the centre, it creates one of the "loops" of the "cardioid". Another idea would be using complex numbers, but I'm not sure how to do that.

The main thing I have no idea how to do analytically is how to consider the "speed" of the orbits and their difference. Should there be some form of Calculus going on?

Edit: I originally posted [a question of the same topic](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26078/does-the-relative-motion-between-planets-other-than-venus-and-earth-form-shapes/26113#26113%5C) in Astronomy Stack Exchange, but I was looking for a more technical answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: probably not the best place to ask, but would you  be able to share how you made that in geogebra? im curious

Comment: Of course :) I inputted two complex numbers of the form $r cis \theta$. Then I created the circumferences for the paths of the two complex numbers so that their paths would be visible in the animation. Then I created a segment between the two numbers, set tracing to on, created some sliders, turned on animation and voila!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose Earth and Venus are at their minimum distance at $t=0$. They will be back to the same position at $t=8$ years, the Earth having made $8$ revolutions around the Sun and Venus $13$.

But they will reach a new position of minimum distance earlier than that. If $T_E=1$ and $T_V=8/13$ are their revolution periods (in years), then at time $t$ they have travelled a fraction $t/T_E$ and $t/T_V$ of a complete revolution, so they are at their minimum distance again if Venus has made one complete revolution more than Earth, that is if
$$
{t\over T_V}={t\over T_E}+1,
\quad\text{whence:}\quad
t={T_ET_V\over T_E-T_V}={8\over5}.
$$
It follows that, during the 8-year Venus-Earth cycle, the two planets reach their minimum distance 5 times: that explains the 5-fold symmetry of your plot.

EDIT.

Here's an animation showing how after $8/5\cdot 360°=576°$ Earth is again at minimum distance from Venus. During the same time Venus has travelled an angle 
$13/8\cdot576=936°=576°+360°$, thus making one full revolution more than Earth.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm probably missing something really obvious, but why are they at a minimum distance if Venus has made one more complete revolution?

Comment: After Earth has made $8/5=1.6$ revolutions and Venus $8/5+1=2.6$ revolutions, then they'll find themselves again at the same angle with respect to the Sun.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks again! Yet, if you check [the gif](https://i.imgur.com/PqJy8lX.gifv), the "loops" of the petal occur when the planets are at a maximum distance from one another, not at minimum distances.

Comment: You can repeat the above argument for maximum distance too. In general, the relative positions of the two planets repeat with a period of $8/5$ years, which is $1/5$ of the absolute period.

Comment: I'm still not convinced on to _why_ they find themselves a the same relative position after Venus has made exactly one more revolution. Where does this come from?

Comment: Suppose Earth and Venus travel on the same orbit, as if it were a car race track. Venus runs faster, so after 1.6 years Venus laps Earth for the first time, after 3.2 years for the second time, after 4.8 years for the third time, after 6.4 years for the fourth time, and after 8 years Venus and Earth are aligned again on the start line.

Comment: Oh okay, I've understood what you meant now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the insane approach ... Let's find the *equation* of the Flower curve!

The curve is the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of line segments determined by the two planet-points, which we can parameterize as
$$P = p \,( \cos 8 t, \sin 8 t ) \qquad Q = q\, ( \cos 13 t, \sin 13 t )$$
where $p$ and $q$ are the radii of the orbits. The line $PQ$ is then
$$f(t) := x \left( p \sin 8 t - q \sin 13 t \right) + y ( - p \cos 8 t + q \cos 13 t ) + p q \sin 5 t \tag{1}$$
so that
$$f^\prime(t) :=  x \left( 8 p \cos 8 t - 13 q \cos 13 t \right) + y \left( 8 p \sin 8 t - 13 q \sin 13 t \right) + 5 p q \cos 5 t \tag{2}$$
To derive the equation of the envelope, "all we have to do" is eliminate $t$ from $f(t)$ and $f^\prime(t)$. With lots of classical envelopes (cardioids, astroids, parabolas, etc), the elimination step is fairly straightforward. Here, with $t$ trapped inside the various sines and cosines, things are a bit complicated. It helps a bit to rewrite the equations in terms of the complex exponential, $\omega := \exp(it)$; it'll help further to define $z := x + i y$ and $\bar{z} := x - i y$. So, we make the substitutions
$$\cos kt = \frac12(\omega^k+\omega^{-k}) \qquad 
\sin kt = \frac1{2i}(\omega^k-\omega^{-k}) \qquad
x = \frac12(z+\bar{z}) \qquad
y = \frac1{2i}(z-\bar{z})$$

Then $(1)$ and $(2)$ become, after clearing denominators,
$$\omega^{26} q \bar{z} - \omega^{21} p \bar{z} - \omega^{18} p q + \omega^8 p q + \omega^5 p z - q z \tag{3}$$
$$13 \omega^{26} q \bar{z} - 8 \omega^{21} p \bar{z} - 5 \omega^{18} p q - 5 \omega^8 p q - 8 \omega^5 p z + 13 q z \tag{4}$$
and *now* "all we have to do" is eliminate $\omega$. Again, this is *conceptually* straightforward: we merely invoke the method of [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), which *Mathematica* graciously implements as its `Resultant[]` function. However, the computational complexity of resultant-finding is related to the sum of the degrees of the polynomials ---here 52--- which causes `Resultant[]` to bog down on my computer. Happily, I was able to get a faster implementation by having *Mathematica* construct the [Sylvester Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvesterMatrix.html) for the polynomials, and take its determinant (which is equivalent to the resultant). The result(ant) is :

$$\begin{align}
&2814749767106560000000000 p^{36} q^{42} \\
+ &\cdots \;\text{($760$ terms)}\; \cdots \\
+ &18258084432456195379316013815625 p^{26} q^{16} z^{13} \bar{z}^{23}
\end{align}\tag{5}$$

Now, instead of restoring $z$ and $\bar{z}$ back to $x$ and $y$ form, I can use to the more-appropriate complex polar form: 
$$z = r \exp(i\theta) \qquad \bar{z} = r\exp(-i\theta)$$
to get
$$\begin{align}
&15879378388503914086400000 \;\left(e^{15i\theta}+e^{-15i\theta} \right)\; p^{39} q^{24} r^{15} \\
+&\phantom{1}3 \left(e^{10i\theta}+e^{-10i\theta} \right)\;p^{26} q^{16} r^{10} (3289829448089600000000000 p^{12} q^{14} + \cdots) \\
-&12 \left(e^{5i\theta}+e^{-5i\theta} \right)\; p^{13} q^8 r^5 (1179648000000000000000 p^{26} q^{26} + \cdots) \\
-&\phantom{1}2\;(1407374883553280000000000 p^{36} q^{42} + \cdots) \\
\end{align} \tag{6}$$
Conveniently, the complex exponentials pair-up to form cosines (with a factor of $2$), so that the polar equation of the Flower of Venus has the form

> $$\begin{align}
> 0 \;=\;\; &31758756777007828172800000 \;\cos 15\theta\; p^{39} q^{24} r^{15} \\
> +&\phantom{1}6 \cos 10\theta \;p^{26} q^{16} r^{10} (3289829448089600000000000 p^{12} q^{14} + \cdots) \\
> -&24 \cos 5\theta \; p^{13} q^8 r^5 (1179648000000000000000 p^{26} q^{26} + \cdots) \\
> -&\phantom{1}2\;(1407374883553280000000000 p^{36} q^{42} + \cdots) \\
> \end{align}\tag{$\star$}$$

Since the arguments of the cosines are all multiples of $5\theta$, the curve must have $5$-fold rotational symmetry. Easy-peasy! $\square$

Of course, this *ad hoc* approach doesn't provide any insights at all into why the $5$-fold symmetry appears, what happens with other "ratio differences", etc. I really just wanted to see for myself how crazy the Flower curve's equation is. I suspect that there must be a way to *anticipate* the symmetry from $(1)$ and $(2)$ (or $(3)$ and $(4)$) without having to actually calculate the resultant; if so, then (presumably) that strategy should apply to arbitrary ratio differences.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I only understood your answer on a very basic level, since I have a pretty basic understanding of the tools you used. However, it is very cool you were able to find the equation of the curve. One question though, what is the explanation of the $8t$ and $13t$ in the arguments of cosine and sine of points $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: @choreley: The $8t$ and $13t$ indicate that the planets orbit at rates $8$-times and $13$-times some "unit" orbit, so that the $P$ makes $8$ orbits in the time it takes $Q$ to make $13$ orbits. I could've made $P$ the "unit" orbit, and then made $Q$'s orbit a function of $\frac{13}{8} t$ (or I could've made $Q$ the "unit", with $P$ in terms of $\frac{8}{13}t$), but I chose to avoid fractions. :)